# setInterval animation with React happens only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, css-animations, use-ref

I want to rotate an image every 5 seconds using React. I am using react hooks. Here's my code:

```
  const imageRef = React.useRef(null)
  React.useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    imageRef.current.style.animationDuration  = "2s"
    imageRef.current.style.transform = "rotate(360deg)"
     
  }, 5000)
}, [])
```

However, this is rotated only the first time. I am expecting in 5 secs for it to be rotated again. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you are setting the style of the element to `transform: rotate(360deg)`, so the `transform` property is interpolating between 360 degress and 360 degrees... which is nothing.

You might be better off using a css animation that starts at `transform:rotate(0deg)`, moves to `transform:rorate(360deg)` over 2 seconds, waits 3 seconds and then repeats for infinity. Assign the element the relevant class, e.g. `.intervalSpin`.

Here is a primer on css animations:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp